# Gerar número aleatório para um array

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um `foreach` que busca os dados de uma tabela e faz um `insert` em outra tabela. Preciso contar a quantidade de registros do `foreach`, e depois gerar uma sequência aleatória, e alimentar um campo do `insert`.

Vejam o código:

```
$dados2 = connection::select('SELECT * FROM tab1');
foreach ($dados2 as $reg) {   
    $campo1 = $reg['campo1'];
    $campo2 = $reg['campo2'];    
    $sequencia_aleatoria = '';                     
}
connection::exec("insert into tab2(campo1,campo2,sequencia_aleatoria) values('$campo1','$campo2','$sequencia_aleatoria')");
```

Espero que tenham compreendido minha dúvida.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer preencher um Array com números de 0 à 100 em ordem aleatória ? Os registros não podem ser inseridos em ordem e você embaralhar a saída ?

Comment: Exato @lucas. Tipo além do autoincremet do insert, quero ter outro campo, para poder alterar essa sequencia quando quiser.

Comment: Mas ele tem que ser randômico.

Comment: ele tem que conter todos os números de 0 até o número total de registros certo ? Então não é aleatório, ele tem uma sequência definida mas é sortido. Você pode popular um array de 0 a 100 por exemplo, e depois fazer um sort

Comment: O segundo exemplo @stderr faz exatamente isso, acho que é o correto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma outra opção é usar as função [`mt_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) para gerar um valor aleatório e [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) para retornar o total de elementos do `array`:

```
$dados2 = connection::select('SELECT * FROM tab1');

foreach ($dados2 as $reg) {   
    $campo1 = $reg['campo1'];
    $campo2 = $reg['campo2'];  

    $sequencia_aleatoria = mt_rand(0, count($dados2);  

    // Para inserir os dados de acordo com a linha atual
    connection::exec("insert into tab2(campo1,campo2,sequencia_aleatoria) values('$campo1','$campo2','$sequencia_aleatoria')");                    
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: Uma segunda opção talvez seja a função [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), para obter o número de linhas resultante do `select`, desta forma não seria necessário `count($dados2)`.</sub>

Ainda assim, existe a possibilidade de gerar números repetidos.

Uma outra forma seria gerar um `array` com uma faixa de números com [`range`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php) e usar a função [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php) para misturar os elementos.

Algo assim:

```
$dados2 = connection::select('SELECT * FROM tab1');
$linhas = $dados2->fetchAll();

$numeros = range(1, count($linhas));

shuffle($numeros); // Mistura os elementos

foreach ($linhas as $i => $linha) { 
    $campo1 = $linha['campo1'];
    $campo2 = $linha['campo2'];  

    $sequencia_aleatoria = $numeros[$i];

    // Para inserir os dados de acordo com a linha atual
    connection::exec("insert into tab2(campo1,campo2,sequencia_aleatoria) values('$campo1','$campo2','$sequencia_aleatoria')");                    
}
```

Comment: no primeiro exemplo atribuiu zero para a variável. Dei um echo no insert, realmente ele atribuiu zero para todas as linhas do insert

Comment: Vou testar seu segundo exemplo

Comment: Também não funciona. Atribui valor zero.

Comment: Sim, eles exigem aleatoriamente

Comment: Por incrível que pareça, mostra a quantidade registros corretamente.

Comment: Vou tentar o mysqli_num_rows

Comment: não funciona também :(

Comment: $linhas = $dados2->fetchAll();
                   $contagem = sizeof($linhas);
             
                    echo $contagem;
                    
                    exit;

                    foreach ($dados2 as $reg) {


                        for ($i = 0; $i <= $contagem; $i++) {
                            $sequencia = rand(0, $contagem);
                        }

Comment: Tentei com sizeof e tbm não deu. @stderr o for está correto. Pois se eu colocar em resultado um valor ele funciona. Mas usando cont, ele não funciona. Mas se dar um echo funciona. Será que não é por causa do foreach. Por não estar dentro do foreach?

Comment: Atribui zero também. :'(

Comment: Sim, vários zeros.

Comment: @EduardoSantos Opa, já é algo. Com base nesse código (http://ideone.com/akQhGp) abaixo de `$sequencias_aleatorias = range(0, $contagem - 1)` coloque um `print_r($sequencias_aleatorias);`, veja o que aparece! **Obs**: Se possível apague os comments anteriores!

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 [2] => 6 [3] => 2 [4] => 4 [5] => 3 [6] => 5 [7] => 0 [8] => 7 )

Comment: @EduardoSantos Estranho acontecer isso, você pode colocar o teu código como está no http://ideone.com e por o link aqui?

Comment: Cara veja isso:  foreach ($dados2 as $reg) {

                        $contagem1 = count($reg);

                        $sequencia = rand(0, $contagem1);
Funcionou, porém repetiu. Como faço pra não repetir?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47013/discussion-on-answer-by-stderr-gerar-numero-aleatorio-para-um-array)

Answer (score 3):

usa a função `uniqueid` do PHP, serial algo do tipo:

```
$dados2 = connection::select('SELECT * FROM tab1');
$contagem=0;

foreach ($dados2 as $reg) {   
    $campo1 = $reg['campo1'];
    $campo2 = $reg['campo2'];    
    $contagem++;                  
}

$sequencia_aleatoria=rand(0,$contagem);
connection::exec("insert into tab2(campo1,campo2,sequencia_aleatoria) values('$campo1','$campo2','$sequencia_aleatoria')");
```

a função [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php) gera um hash baseado nos milissegundos então não há possibilidade de repetição.

Acho que seu código seria então assim:

```
$dados2 = connection::select('SELECT * FROM tab1');
$numero=count(dados2);

foreach ($dados2 as $reg) {   
    $campo1 = $reg['campo1'];
    $campo2 = $reg['campo2'];    
    $sequencia_aleatoria=rand(0,$numero);

    connection::exec("insert into tab2(campo1,campo2,sequencia_aleatoria) values('$campo1','$campo2','$sequencia_aleatoria')");   
    unset($sequencia_aleatoria);    
}
```

Roda isso q funciona

```
<?php
$contagem=420; // aqui iioria o count($resultado);
for($i=0;$i<=$contagem;$i++){
    echo rand(0,$contagem)."<br>";
}
?>
```

a logica he a mesma e ta rolando.

testa online aqui
http://phptester.net/

em vez d vc fazer um foreach faz um for

```
$dados2 = connection::select('SELECT * FROM tab1');
$numero=count(dados2);

for($i=0;$i<$numero;i++) { 
    $reg=$dados2[$i];  
    $campo1 = $reg['campo1'];
    $campo2 = $reg['campo2'];    
    $sequencia_aleatoria=rand(0,$numero);

    connection::exec("insert into tab2(campo1,campo2,sequencia_aleatoria) values('$campo1','$campo2','$sequencia_aleatoria')");   
    unset($sequencia_aleatoria);    
}
```

Comment: Não é isso que preciso. Quero assim, se tiver 100 registros, ele coloca uma ordem aleatória de 0 até 100. Entendeu? Como expliquei, ele precisa contar os registros e atribuir uma sequencia aleatória sem repetir.

Comment: entendi, vou arrumar o cod.

Comment: Dessa maneira ele repete rs

Comment: sim pq no seu cod original vc esta inserindo no db fora do seu foreach

Comment: ainda repete, mais que no código anterior.

Comment: nao entendi o q repete explica melhor

Comment: Repete o valor da variavel $sequencia_aleatória. Tenho 420 registros, o número 1 por exemplo foi inserido 46 vezes.

Comment: O segundo exemplo não funcionou. Atribui zero.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=<?php\n$contagem=420; // aqui iioria o count($resultado);\nfor($i=0;$i<=$contagem;$i++){\n\techo rand(0,$contagem)."<br>";\n}\n?>

Comment: copia tudo isso no seu navegador aki funciona. é so vc usa a mesma logica

Comment: Jasar, funcionou se atribuir o valor count. Mas usando count($resultado) não funciona. Também tentei assim  $rows = $dados2->fetchAll();
                    $contagem = count($rows); E não funcinou.

Comment: Acredito que agora o problema esteja na contagem do array